# How to know which Catia Body is publication if names of all the bodies are same

Tags: vba, catia

I have been looking for an answer to this question for 5 days now,
The question is:
If I have many bodies with the same name and one of them is released as a publication. Now, how can I know which body is released as a publication. Is there a way to compare a publication with each body (please remember that the names of bodies are the same). And can I access the body with the publication object? please respond if you have any idea about it.
Thanks

[image: The image represents the above question.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therefor you can use the selection as a workaround:
Get the reference of the publication and select this reference

```vb
Sub CATMain()

Set oPartDocument = Catia.ActiveDocument
Set oPublication = oPartDocument.Product.Publications.Item(1)
Set oSel = oPartDocument.Selection

Set oReference = oPublication.Valuation

oSel.Clear
oSel.Add oReference

Set oSelObject = oSel.Item2(1).Value

MsgBox oSelObject.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shrotter, i tried as you said but the selection object (oSel) is not adding the reference object as shown in above code

Comment: Hi, so are oPublication and oSel assigned (_Set_)? On my test this code works.

Comment: Thank you Shrotter for the help, the workaround works. There was a little mistake in my code.